# Clock is missing ubuntu 15

Tags: 15.10, locale, clock

After install ubuntu 15, my clock is missing also I've checked my locale and there is an error too.
"locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory"
 I don't know if all there are the same error, or two errors

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QDPL.png)

Sorry for my english :)

Comment: Is this a VPS (virtual machine) ?

Comment: Please don't add code as screenshots.

Comment: isn't VPS (virtual machine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out if the missing clock is due to the broken locale by fixing the locale.

Open **Language Support**, select the **Regional Formats** tab, switch to some other option but the one you want, and finally switch to the desired option ("Português (Brasil)"?).

Plus log out and log in again.